# Python bind a Shift key press to a command

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like activate a command upon shift press and another command upon shift release. I need something like ShiftPress or ShiftRelease. Any ideas?
 `btn.bind('', lambda event, a=a: cmd(a))`

Comment: If you could provide some more info on your use case it would be helpful, as in this case python can detect shift being pressed, but why exactly do you need to detect when it is released? Perhaps a workaround can be proposed accordingly.

Comment: What is wrong with binding to `'<KeyPress-Shift_L>'` and `'<KeyRelease-Shift_L>'` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like what you want is not possible with Tkinter alone

The [current docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) and the [old docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111211515id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm#events) aren't very helpful about what all events are possible to bind, but we can find more detail in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L1353).

This gives us something to test:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()

        self.entry = tk.Entry()
        self.entry.pack()

        self.entry.bind(
            "<Key>", lambda e: print(f"<Key> {e.char!r}")
        )
        self.entry.bind(
            "<Shift-KeyPress>", lambda e: print(f"<Shift-KeyPress> {e.char!r}")
        )
        self.entry.bind(
            "<Shift-KeyRelease>", lambda e: print(f"<Shift-KeyRelease> {e.char!r}")
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Run this and click into the input box. This just prints `<Shift-KeyPress> ''` when you press and release the shift key.

Unfortunately it seems that because `Shift` is a "modifier" key it does not trigger a release event when pressed by itself, only the press down event.

#### Update

With some more experimentation we can do better:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()

        self.entry = tk.Entry()
        self.entry.pack()

        self.entry.bind(
            "<KeyRelease>", lambda e: print(repr(e))
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Run this and click into the input box. Now we can see printed:

```
<KeyRelease event keysym=Shift_L keycode=939587838 x=126 y=14>
<KeyRelease event keysym=Shift_R keycode=1006696702 x=126 y=14>
```

So it seems like it *is* possible to detect key release events for Shift keys using tkinter.

We can now put this together into a cleaner solution:

```py
import tkinter as tk


SHIFT_KEYS = {"Shift_L", "Shift_R"}


def shift_press(event):
    if event.keysym in SHIFT_KEYS:
        print("Shift press")


def shift_release(event):
    if event.keysym in SHIFT_KEYS:
        print("Shift release")


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()

        self.entry = tk.Entry()
        self.entry.pack()

        self.entry.bind("<KeyPress>", shift_press)
        self.entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", shift_release)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

I don't know tkinter, but I guess you can make the input box invisible somehow or find some other element that can capture keyboard events.

#### Update 2

With help from the comment by @Delrius Euphoria it turns out we can actually do this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


def shift_press(event):
    print("Shift press")


def shift_release(event):
    print("Shift release")


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()

        self.entry = tk.Entry()
        self.entry.pack()

        self.entry.bind("<KeyPress-Shift_L>", shift_press)
        self.entry.bind("<KeyPress-Shift_R>", shift_press)
        self.entry.bind("<KeyRelease-Shift_L>", shift_release)
        self.entry.bind("<KeyRelease-Shift_R>", shift_release)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

With the power of hindsight we can now Google for the answer, e.g. here https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/key-names.html gives a list of key names that includes `Shift_L` and `Shift_R`.

Comment: Can you also explain what `e.char!r` means?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria that is f-string syntax https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals so `print(f"{e.char!r})"` is the same as `print(repr(e.char))`... I'm not sure why the repr is needed but the [old docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111211515id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) and the [src code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L239) both do it so maybe it is

Answer (score 1):

in my code I used:

```
editor.bind("<Shift-Button-1>", lambda event: mouse_handling(event, 'shiftbtn1click'))
editor.bind("<Shift-ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: mouse_handling(event, 'shiftbtn1release'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).