# What keysym does the <Button-1> (left mouse button )have?

Tags: python, tkinter, binding

I have a function:

```
def sound(self,event):
        playsound('monkey_sound.wav', block=False)
```

It responds to pressing only one key - the left mouse button. I have to make it in that way, that sound will be different depending on the  pressed key  (left mouse button or right mouse button). But there should be only one function.

Here is fragment of my code:

```
class monkey:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.photo = PhotoImage(file='C:\\monkey_exe\\monkey.png')
        self.id=canvas.create_image(30,30,anchor=NW,image=self.photo)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Motion>', self.motion)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Button-1>', self.sound)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Button-2>', self.sound)
    def motion(self,event):
        canvas.coords(self.id, event.x-50, event.y-108)
    def sound(self,event):
        playsound('monkey_sound.wav', block=False)
```

So the two keys must be binded to the same function, but they must play different sounds. But I don't know *keysym*'s of left mouse button and right mouse button.

Comment: I don't know the answer but I answered similar question recently - perhaps by putting some `print` debugging in you can get tkinter to tell you the distinct codes you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/71222201/202168

Comment: @Anentropic Your program does not respond when I press the left mouse button or the right mouse button

Comment: yes you might need to adapt it for mouse events rather than keyboard events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure on what the symbol of the mouse buttons, but I found a decent alternative with using the `event.num` property...

```py
def sound(self, event):
    if event.num == 1: #left mouse button
        playsound("monkey_sound1.wav", block=false)

    elif event.num == 2: #middle mouse button
        playsound("monkey_sound2.wav", block=false)

    elif event.num == 3: #right mouse button
        playsound("monkey_sound3.wav", block=false)
```

The `event.num` will return a number between 1-3 (unless you bind the function to another key/button).